# YARN capacity scheduler queues are not running as per configured ACL

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I've been using the following configuration for YARN capacity scheduler:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=tier1,tier2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier1.capacity=65
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier1.maximum-capacity=75
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier1.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier2.capacity=35
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier2.maximum-capacity=75
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier2.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier1.acl_submit_applications=user1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.tier2.acl_submit_applications=user2
```

Now as per my understanding of capacity scheduler, when I run a job with user **user1**, it should use **tier1 queue** and when I run a job with user **user2** logged in (or explicitly by using sudo - user2), it should use **tier2 queue**. However, system is not using these queues.

The second issue I've been facing is described below:

**user1** should not be able to submit the job to **tier2** queue as per the above configuration.

**user2** should not be able to submit the job to **tier**1 queue as per the above configuration.

when I run the following command :

```
sudo -u user1 hdfs yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.2.1.2.1-471.jar pi -D mapreduce.job.queuename=tier2 2 100000
```

the job runs successfully which should not be the case.

Please suggest a possible work around.

Comment: Hey! i am also facing the same issue, have u resolved ? Please let me know resolution steps ?

Comment: I have the same problem, please ¿have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use below properties in scheduler.capacity.xml file
`yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.it.user-limit-factor=2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.price.user-limit-factor=1`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `"yarn.acl.enable":"true"` in yarn-site.xml, without this property capacity-scheduler will not honor your ACL properties